# A problem that I'm not sure whether to use Weierstrass Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

$\text{Let }f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R\text{ be a continuous function}$
Evaluate the function
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)\,dx$$

Here is my work:

Given $\epsilon \gt 0$,since $f(x) \in C^0[0,1]$, by Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, there is a polynomial $p(x)$ s.t. $$|f(x)-p(x)|\lt \varepsilon$$ So we have 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}x^n|f(x)-p(x)|\,dx & \lt \int_{0}^{1}x^n\varepsilon\, dx\\
& = \left[\varepsilon\,\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \right]_{0}^{1}\\
& = \frac{\varepsilon}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$

Since $p(x)$ is a polynomial, suppose it has degree $m$, and has the form
$$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_mx^m$$
$a_i\in \Bbb R\text{ for each }i$. Integrate it we get
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^n\,p(x)\,dx=\frac{a_0}{n+1}+\frac{a_1}{n+2}+\frac{a_2}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{a_m}{n+m+1}$$
By triangle inequality, $0\le |f(x)|\le |f(x)-p(x)|+|p(x)|$, so
$$
\begin{align}
0\le \int_{0}^{1}x^n\,|f(x)|\,dx & \le \int_{0}^{1}x^n|f(x)-p(x)|\,dx+\int_{0}^{1}x^n|p(x)|\,dx\\
& \le \int_{0}^{1}x^n|f(x)-p(x)|\,dx+\int_{0}^{1}x^n\sum_{i=0}^{m}\lvert a_ix^i\rvert\,dx
\end{align}
$$
But we know that both $\int_{0}^{1}x^n|f(x)-p(x)|\,dx\text{ and }\int_{0}^{1}x^n\sum_{i=0}^{m}\lvert a_ix^i\rvert\,dx$ goes to $0 \text{ as }n\to \infty$
Then by pinching, $$\int_{0}^{1}x^n\,|f(x)|\,dx\to 0\text{ as }n\to \infty$$
then $$\int_{0}^{1}x^n\,f(x)\,dx\to 0\text{ as }n\to \infty$$

I don't I'm do the right thing? because I just come up with this idea, and seems strange.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An idea:

Since $\;f\;$ continuous in a closed, bounded interval it is bounded there, say by $\;M\;$ , and then

$$\left|\int_0^1 x^nf(x)\,dx\right|\le\int_0^1 x^n|f(x)|dx\le M\int_0^1x^ndx=\frac M{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Indeed Weierstrass theorem....but *not* the approximation one. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(x)$ is continuous, then there exist $m,M$ such that $m\le f(x) \le M$. Do you have any idea from here?

Answer (score 2):

I did not go over all your steps to check if there is a mistake, but the approach is correct - however, the Weierstrass approximation theorem is an unnecessarily powerful tool. You can get away with a simpler tool: Use Weierstrass's theorem saying that a continuous function on a closed interval is bounded, then bound the integral using the bound on the function $f$, evaluate and apply the pinching theorem.