# More about Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I just fix [the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248342/a-problem-that-im-not-sure-whether-to-use-weierstrass-approximation-theorem), but now I have another one

$\text{Let }f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R\text{ be a continuous function}$
Evaluate the function
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)\,dx$$

My idea is to do just like what I've done in [the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248342/a-problem-that-im-not-sure-whether-to-use-weierstrass-approximation-theorem), only to multiply $n$ in the integral, becomes
$$
\begin{align}
0\le n\int_{0}^{1}x^n\,|f(x)|\,dx & \le n\int_{0}^{1}x^n|f(x)-p(x)|\,dx+n\int_{0}^{1}x^n|p(x)|\,dx\\
& \le n\int_{0}^{1}x^n|f(x)-p(x)|\,dx+n\int_{0}^{1}x^n\sum_{i=0}^{m}\lvert a_ix^i\rvert\,dx
\end{align}
$$
and $$n\int_{0}^{1}x^np(x)\,dx=\frac{na_0}{n+1}+\frac{na_1}{n+2}+\frac{na_2}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{na_m}{n+m+1}
 \to p(1)$$
as $n\to\infty$.

But I stuck because first, I'm doing $|f(x)|$ not $f(x)$

and second, I just know it's upper bound, and I can't use pinching because the lower bound is $0$

I want to compute its lower bound but how?

Comment: Weren't you **already** given *how* to evaluate that limit?? Why are you asking about it again and using a big, and unnecessary, cannon as Weierstrass' Approximation Theorem... **again** ?

Comment: because I don't know how to use that method.

Comment: f is boounded by M and nM/n+1 -> M as n is big, but I don't know what M is.

Comment: @VitoChou you don't need to know what $M$ is, you just need to know that such an $M$ exists.

Comment: @VitoChou In your approach, you don't "know what $p(x)$ is" by the exact same token

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the existence of $M$ here does not give anything useful - only that if the limit exists, then it is bounded by $M$.

Comment: uh, the previous one $\left|\int_0^1 x^nf(x)\,dx\right|\le\int_0^1 x^n|f(x)|dx\le M\int_0^1x^ndx=\frac M{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$

but now become$\left|n\int_0^1 x^nf(x)\,dx\right|\le n\int_0^1 x^n|f(x)|dx\le Mn\int_0^1x^ndx=\frac {nM}{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}M$

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I had misread, I thought it was the same question as last time

Comment: @VitoChou You have just proved a $\limsup$ statement, not worked out the limit.

Comment: @Frank hence "I want to compute its lower bound but how?"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom he proves an upper bound

Comment: I also read exactly the same limit as in the other question before, so either that was typo corrected later, or else I misread...

Comment: @frank ,I don't really need worked out that? did I misunderstanding the problem...

Comment: @VitoChou I'm not sure what's going on in these comments, but I hope my answer below helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us suppose that in addition $f$ is $C^1$. We already know (your previous question) that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx=0$, therefore we can study $$\int_0^1(n+1)x^nf(x)dx$$instead.

We integrate by parts to obtain
$$x^{n+1}f(x)\big|_{x=0}^{x=1} - \int_0^1 x^{n+1}f'(x)dx \to f(1)\quad \text{as}\quad n\to\infty$$
by your previous question.

Now in the case where $f$ is not necessarily differentiable, we can find a $C^1$ uniform approximation (use Weierstrass-Stone theorem if you want):

$$\forall \varepsilon>0\exists g\in C^1[0,1]\quad \text{such that}\quad \|f-g\|_\infty<\varepsilon.$$ Moreover, we can choose $g$ such that $g(1)=f(1)$.

Therefore $$ n\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx= \int_0^1nx^n(f(x)-g(x))dx + \int_0^1nx^n g(x)dx.$$

The first term can be made arbitrarily small by a choice of $g$:
$$\int_0^1|nx^n(f(x)-g(x))|dx\le \varepsilon \int_0^1nx^n = \varepsilon \frac{n}{n+1}$$
and the second one converges to $g(1)=f(1)$ by the first part of this answer.

Therefore, we can conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx=f(1).$$

Comment: I just has the idea but don't know how to write it down, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$
\psi_n(x)=(n+1)x^n
$$
We have that $\psi_n(x)\ge0$ and $\int_0^1\psi_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1$. Furthermore, on $[0,1-\delta]$
$$
\|\psi_n(x)\|_\infty\le(n+1)(1-\delta)^n
$$
and, for any $0\lt\delta\lt1$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(n+1)(1-\delta)^n=0$.

Since $f$ is continuous, given $\epsilon\gt0$, there is a $0\lt\delta\lt1$ so that for all $1-\delta\le x\le1$, we have $|f(x)-f(1)|\le\epsilon$.
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\int_0^1\psi_n(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-f(1)\,\right|
&=\left|\,\int_0^1\psi_n(x)(f(x)-f(1))\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\\
&\le\int_0^1\psi_n(x)\left|f(x)-f(1)\right|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{1-\delta}\color{#C00000}{\psi_n(x)}\color{#00A000}{\left|f(x)-f(1)\right|}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&+\int_{1-\delta}^1\color{#0000F0}{\psi_n(x)}\color{#C08000}{\left|f(x)-f(1)\right|}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[9pt]
&\le\color{#C00000}{(n+1)(1-\delta)^n}\color{#00A000}{(\|f\|_1+|f(1)|)}\\[12pt]
&+\color{#0000F0}{1}\cdot\color{#C08000}{\epsilon}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\,\int_0^1\psi_n(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-f(1)\,\right|\le\epsilon
$$
and since $\epsilon\gt0$ was arbitrary, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\,\int_0^1\psi_n(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-f(1)\,\right|=0
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1nx^nf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1\psi_n(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=f(1)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate any such $f$ by a continuously differentiable function. For such a function it is easy to prove using integration by parts:

$$n\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx = \frac{n}{n+1} x^{n+1}f(x) \bigg{\vert}_0^1 - \frac{n}{n+1} \int_0^1 x^{n+1} f(x)dx. $$

The first term goes to $f(1)$. The second one goes to $0$ by your previous question.

I was going to use an $L^2$ approximation $g$ to $f$, so that $g \in C^2$ and $||f-g||_{L^2}< \epsilon$, and such that $g(1)=f(1)$. Then I can write

$$\bigg{\vert} n\int x^n(f(x)-g(x)dx \bigg{\vert} \leq \epsilon n \bigg{\vert}\int x^{2n} dx \bigg{\vert} \leq \epsilon \frac{n}{2n+1.}$$

Comment: So if $f_k$ is the $k$th approximation (i.e. $f_k \to f$ uniformly with $f_k$ smooth), you'll have that the limit we want to compute is equal to
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} n \int_0^1 x^n f_k(x) \,dx
$$
how do you justify an interchange of these limits?

Comment: oh I forget the integration by part....

Comment: @Omnomnomnom There is no such problem. I was about to add to my answer, by the other answer beat me to it.

Comment: @Frank Shouldn't the last integrand in the first equation be $x^{n+1}f'(x)dx$